# Laravel When I convert to json groupby disappears

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a code like the one below. Let the data coming from "fiyat" and "kampanyafiyat" relations are grouped according to the column named type in these tables.

```
    $services = Servis::with('fiyat')
        ->with('kampanyafiyat')
        ->get()
        ->transform(function($servis) {
            return tap($servis, function($servis) {
                $servis->fiyat = $servis->fiyat
                    ->groupBy('tip');
                    
                $servis->kampanyafiyat = $servis->kampanyafiyat
                    ->groupBy('tip');
            });
        })
        ->all();
```

`dd($ services);` I added the code and saw on the screen that the groupBy operation was successful.

When I want it as json, groupBy disappears and comes as default.

`return response()->json(['status' => true, 'services'=> $services],200);`

When I express as json_encode(), groupBy gets lost.

json it sounds like the following when I want it.

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "hizmet":"tasima",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "fiyat":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"saatlik",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"gunluk",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"haftalik",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ],
      "kampanyafiyat":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"saatlik",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"gunluk",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"haftalik",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Actually, what I want to happen is as follows.

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "hizmet":"tasima",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "fiyat":{
         "saatlik":{
            "id":1,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"saatlik",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         "gunluk":{
            "id":3,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"gunluk",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         "haftalik":{
            "id":5,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"haftalik",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      },
      "kampanyafiyat":{
         "saatlik":{
            "id":1,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"saatlik",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         "gunluk":{
            "id":3,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"gunluk",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         "haftalik":{
            "id":5,
            "servis_id":1,
            "tip":"haftalik",
            "yillik":"8.35",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Use `toArray()` before passing data to `response`

Comment: toArray(); groupBy disappears in expressions again @BABAKASHRAFI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using the `setRelation` method could help.

```
$services = Servis::with('fiyat')
    ->with('kampanyafiyat')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($servis) {
        $servis->setRelation('fiyat', $servis->fiyat->groupBy('tip'));
        $servis->setRelation('kampanyafiyat', $servis->kampanyafiyat->groupBy('tip'));

        return $servis;
    })
    ->all();
```